# Why jqLite is not triggering resize event?

Tags: javascript, browser, jqlite

This simple code:

```
$(document).find('.some-class-name').on('resize', function () { alert("HEY"); });
```

Is not working when I resize the window? I am typing it in browsers console so there should not be any issues with "no elements were found". Does the jqLite support resize event? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of these should work:

```
$('.some-class').resize(function(){alert('HEY'); });

$(document).find('.scome-class').resize(function(){alert('HEY'); });

$($(document).find('.scome-class')).resize(function(){alert('HEY'); });
```

Comment: Does not work. First one doesn't have a `find` method in `document` object, and the second one just is not triggered.

Comment: Updated. 'As the .resize() method is just a shorthand for .on( "resize", handler )' https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Did you tried to run this code on jqLite? Its not working for me at all (no `resize` function).

Comment: Which version of jqLite ?